# Constructor refers to missing type context

Tags: android, constructor, android-context

I have written a class with the following constructor

```
public CustomDialog(Context context)
```

But when I try to do this in my activity

```
CustomDialog diag = new CustomDialog(getApplicationContext()){/*stuff here*/};
```

I get the error `The constructor CustomDialog(Context) refers to the missing type Context`

What does this mean? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does this mean?

AFAIK, either:

- You are missing the `import android.content.Context`, or
- Your project is messed up, and the compiler cannot find `android.content.Context` in your build path

Comment: I can see `android.content.Context` in the imports section, what should I do to fix(or test) case 2?

Comment: @jcw: That's difficult to answer. Whether you are building from Eclipse with ADT, or Ant, the `android.jar` for your build target should be automatically included.

Comment: Okay, well that looks sufficiently confusing. Fortunately this is a small project, so I will just copy all the classes into a new project and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Well, that worked..... I have no clue as to why. Accepted your answer for pushing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone else had this issue: I had the same problem with some code that called a method from the Play Licensing library. I fixed it by using **Project > Clean** on Play Licensing project (as opposed to the project where the error was showing up).

Answer (score 5):

First you should fix all other errors in your code than you should repeat  **Project -> Clean** in Eclipse to see if the error was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding some code and then removing it again. For example, add an empty statement and then remove it. Eclipse should check for errors again and not find your error.

Answer (score 0):

Did a maven update on the project, it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Project->Clean worked for me.